# My return-statement doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist, return

I want to make an arraylist with 100 numbers randomly chosen from 0-9.
Then I want java to print the average value and the most used number in the arraylist.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class exercarrlist {

//main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random n = new Random();

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        list1.add(n.nextInt(9));
    }
    Average(list1);
    most(list1);
}

//average
public static int Average(ArrayList<Integer> input){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int getal: input) {
         sum +=getal;
  }
    int gemiddelde = sum / input.size();
    return gemiddelde;
}
//most seen in arraylist
public static int most(ArrayList<Integer> input){
    int[] counts = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for(int getal: counts){
        counts[getal]++;
    }
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
        if(counts[i]>max){
            max=i;
        }
    }
    return max;

}
}
```

I want java to print max and gemiddelde on the screen, but it won't. Can you help me to find the mistake?

Comment: What's the actual problem? `It won't` isn't an error or ouput!

Comment: Maybe you should add something that prints it like `System.Out.Println()`? Otherwise nothing will be printed..

Answer (score 1):

You print to console like this:

```
System.out.println(average(list1)); //average should be downcased, it's not a class
System.out.println(most(list1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print, so print. The fact that your method returns something does not make this value printed. Actually you do no use value returned from `most()` at all:

```
most(list1);
```

If you want to print use:

```
System.out.println(most(list1));
```

Now start learning java.

Answer (score 0):

For nextInt read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) please.

And sometimes it helps others to have a clearer name.
You switched counts and inputs.

```
int[] countsIndexedByGetal = new int[10]; // All zeero.
for (int getal: inputs) {
    countsIndexedByGetal[getal]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some changes:

- most(list) method should be like this, your first loop is wrong i think.

  ```
  public static int most(ArrayList<Integer> input){
      int[] counts = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

      for(int getal: **input**){
          counts[getal]++;
      }

      int max = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
          if(counts[i]>max){
              max=i;
          }
      }

      return max;
  }
  ```
- to print it use sysout:

  ```
  System.out.println(Average(list1));
  System.out.println(most(list1));
  ```

Comment: sorry for bad formatting.. i m new to stackoverflow

Comment: replace **counts** with input in **most()** method.
can't comment on main question. don't have enough reputations.